# Carbon Design Systems UI Shell component is not working in Code Pen

Tags: html, css, codepen

I am trying to use the Carbon Design's UI Shell component in [CodePen](https://codepen.io/fbagirov/pen/eajYwW).

The code for the component is [here](https://www.carbondesignsystem.com/experimental/ui-shell/code) and the UI looks like this:

```
<header class="bx--header" role="banner" aria-label="IBM Platform Name" data-header>
 <a class="bx--skip-to-content" href="#main-content" tabindex="0">Skip to main content</a>
  <button class="bx--header__menu-trigger bx--header__action" aria-label="Open menu" title="Open menu"
data-navigation-menu-panel-label-expand="Open menu" data-navigation-menu-panel-label-collapse="Close menu"
data-navigation-menu-target="#navigation-menu-fthewlqilpo">
<svg focusable="false" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" style="will-change: transform;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" aria-hidden="true" class="bx--navigation-menu-panel-collapse-icon" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><path d="M24 9.4L22.6 8 16 14.6 9.4 8 8 9.4l6.6 6.6L8 22.6 9.4 24l6.6-6.6 6.6 6.6 1.4-1.4-6.6-6.6L24 9.4z"></path></svg>
<svg focusable="false" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" style="will-change: transform;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" aria-hidden="true" class="bx--navigation-menu-panel-expand-icon" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20"><path d="M2 14.8h16V16H2zm0-3.6h16v1.2H2zm0-3.6h16v1.2H2zM2 4h16v1.2H2z"></path></svg>
</button>
... 
<!-- the rest of the code can be seen in Code Pen -->
```

[image]

But when I copy the code into the CodePen, the output looks like the css is missing:

[image]

What is a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a few things in the setup, namely adding the CDN and setting the CSS and javascript preprocessors.

You can read more about how to add the CDN here 
https://www.carbondesignsystem.com/getting-started/developers/vanilla

What's cool though is this company already made a bunch of codepens for you to test out. This may help!

https://codepen.io/collection/XqRbEz/

The first example makes a header just like your codepen, the difference is they use their cloud header

```
<nav class="bx--cloud-header">
```

I would suggest you fork one of the existing codepens so that you can use their setup to run any other tests that you would like.

In this example, you can see that they do have a hamburger within their header.
https://codepen.io/team/carbon/pen/LedzoM

Personally I work with layouts like this that already have the implemented burger component.
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/examples/layouts/googleContacts

I also work alot with these tried and tested templates. They are all done in HTML and CSS. This man is a genius.
https://html5up.net/

Comment: I've set everything according to the links - thanks! But it is still not showing me the right view. Also, thanks for the CodePen links, but it does not have UIShell, only Navigation bar, which I am aware of. I would like to use the UIShell, because adding search functionality and hamburger menus are a pain with the Navigation bar.

Comment: That UIShell is experimental code has been updated since Carbon moved to v10. That means that the new styles are not applied to the old classifiers.

Comment: Whatever the case, you can build a UI Shell on your own!

Comment: You add the components separately so that you follow the shell guidelines

Comment: that's what I tried to do after UIShell issues, but I do not think all of the components are available separately. For example, I don't see SideNav (Hamburger) in the Carbon library. That's the issue.

Comment: This is an example of poor documentation. You have two options: reverse engineer their work or ask them directly for help. In this case, I would suggest you jump ship for a new framework

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem myself.
You have missed adding one dependency that wraps up CSS over carbon components.

Just do `yarn add sass` or `npm add sass`

After this, your UI should render properly.